# Expo Go Crashing/ Video Upload Failing

Tags: react-native, file-upload, expo, fetch-api

I have two bugs and I am not even sure if they are connected. First whenever I try to upload a video via Expo Go (iOs Simulator or physical device) the app crashes.
On android it doesn't crash but throws "[TypeError: Network request failed]"

my video:

```
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    setUploadFile(result.assets[0])
```

my formData:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", uploadFile);
const videoOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer '...',
  },
  body: uploadFile
};
```

the api request:

```
fetch(postVideos.url, videoOptions)
      .then((something))
      .catch((something))
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What service are you uploading the files to? Without more information, try this fix.

If you can upload a blob, try that. I believe I've read that ImagePicker only returns a ref to the image. You can use fetch to get a blob of the image using that url.

```
const response = await fetch('file uri')
const blob = response.blob()
```